# Deployment error with JAX-RS 2.0 RESTful webservice and tomcat 8.0

Tags: web-services, rest, maven, tomcat, jax-rs

I am novice to writing REST WebServices.
Currently I am trying to write a RESTful service using jersey-2.x and tomcat 8.0
However, when I try to deploy in eclipse, it gives me error as follows :

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;`

What I did is :

1. wrote below classes :

   ```
   @ApplicationPath("resources")
   public class RestTestApplication extends Application
   {
       @Override
       public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
           final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
           // register root resource
           classes.add(HelloResource.class);
           return classes;
       }
   }

   @Path("sayhello")
   public class HelloResource
   {
       @GET
       @Produces("text/plain")
       public String sayhello ()
       {
           return "Hi, How are you !!";
       }
   }
   ```
2. downloaded from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/bundles/jaxrs-ri/2.12/jaxrs-ri-2.12.zip
3. downloaded jsr311-api-1.1.2.r612.jar
4. copied all *.jar files from jaxrs-ri-2.12.zip and jsr311-api-1.1.2.r612.jar to WEB-INF/lib and also imported to build path.
5. Edited web.xml as below :

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
       <display-name>RestWS</display-name>
   <welcome-file-list>
       <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
       <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
       <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
       <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
       <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
       <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list> 
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>Rest Test</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
           <param-value>com.example</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>Rest Test</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   </web-app>`
   ```
6. run as-->run on server
7. Getting the error mentioned above.

please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its because you have both jars from `jaxrs-ri-2.12.zip` and `jsr311-api-1.1.2.r612.jar` in your classpath.  `jsr311-api-1.1.2.r612.jar` has the older implementation of JAX-RS API. Your `Application` class that your `RestTestApplication` extends from is from the `jsr311-api-1.1.2.r612.jar`; however at runtime the `Application` class from your jaxrs jar in `jaxrs-ri-2.12.zip` is being referred to. Removing the `jsr311` jar from your WEBINF/lib should hopefully resolve the issue.

If you decompile the `Application` class from both the jars you will notice that the one in `jsr311` jar doesn't have `getProperties` method and hence the `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` error.

Comment: Its working now. Thanks for the solution along with in detail explanation.